# Change the UIScrollView's swipe direction to inverse for Arabic people

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, arabic, swipe-gesture

I've added a `UIScrollView` with pagination enabled. In Arabic countries usual is swipe is right to left.

Is this possible with `UIScrollView`?

Comment: UIScrollView swipes in both direction. all you have to do is to set the initial position of scrollView

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a contentView that would want a scrollView for. This is the approach I would use. Set the scrollView's contentSize to whatever size your contentView has. Add the contentView to your view. Set on offset to the scrollView, and if you support 2 screen sizes there should be a difference of 158 between the views.

```
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;
    scrollView.contentSize=self.contentView.frame.size;
    [self.view addSubview:self.contentView];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(286, 0.0f)];//Put the offset here so it swipes right to left. For iPhone 5/5s
    self.title = @"the ContentView";

}
else{
    UIScrollView *scrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;
    scrollView.contentSize=self.contentView.frame.size;
    [self.view addSubview:self.contentView];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(444, 0.0f)]; //Put the offset here so it swipes right to left. For iPhone 3gs/4/4s
        self.title = @"The ContentView";
}
```

Comment: do you mean, that I should paste this code in scrollViewDidScroll:?

Comment: In the corresponding UIViewController that manages the scrollview and the view you wish to display inside. I have called that contentView. You need to hook them up via InterfaceBuilder and create a property for the contentView.